# How can I run an OpenGL program on a headless server?

Tags: server, xorg, opengl, headless

I'm working on a server application that does image processing (and in part, using freeglut).  This application will be deployed on a headless server and when I run it there, I get errors saying that freeglut couldn't open a display.
I figured this would be an issue, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.  My server is limited in resources, so it would be good if I didn't have to install X11 and run it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could try running a VNC server or a dummy X server.

However, it may be that freeglut will connect and then immediately die because that server doesn't have any GL support.

Comment: Could you give more details? What commands will achieve this?

Comment: If your preferred search engine can't find anything for "vnc server" or "dummy x server", there's something terribly wrong with it. If it did find something but you're having trouble understanding it, or getting it to work - you should feel free to ask a question of your own with the "Ask Question" button at the top right. Comments aren't really designed for asking new questions, and it's not obvious the extra detail is useful for the original question here.